# Desktop computer won't boot with beep sounds

Tags: boot

My LG desktop computer won't boot.

It makes two short beeps, pause, and 6 consecutive beeps.

(please listen to the linked mp3 file)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5s7k1ockqp9zc8/bootingbeep.mp3?dl=0

Comment: What's the motherboard model? It should be printed on the motherboard somewhere in a (relatively) large font. After you discover it, you should be able to find a user manual for it online.

Comment: The POST beep codes vary by manufacturer.  But note that the beeps may not all be from the POST.  If the system is set to enumerate USB devices, you will get a beep for each one after the POST.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a beep-code. It is a signal that something is wrong such as hardware failure or missing components (e.g. RAM). What, if anything, displays on screen when the beeping happens?

What the beeps mean differ depending on your BIOS. What make of BIOS is in your PC? It should be displayed at the top of the screen when it boots.

A list of different beep codes can be found [here](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm).

Comment: Usually you can find them in the motherboard manual.

Comment: If he has an "LG" PC I am guessing this was brought as a single unit and the manual amounts to how to connect the PC up and power it on. I will be amazed if it was a list of beep-codes in there.

Comment: I bought a used one and can't find what BIOS or motherboard it has.

Comment: There is nothing displayed on the monitor.

Comment: Then that might be the issue. Is it a separate graphics card or one built-in to the motherboard? Can you open the case and get a mother board model number?

Comment: @Darren Actually it's my friend's computer. I guess it has built-in graphics

Answer (score 0):

In the audio file it sounds like an older non-UEFI system. The first 2 beeps are your post beeps of the system initiating and the 6 consecutive beeps on a vast amount of pc's and laptops indicate a video card or chip failure.... which is actually what you confirmed this saying, "there is nothing displayed ...." In older systems, the POST initiates a "self test" which check voltages of hardware (like video) to make sure they are functioning correctly and then load a basic driver so that you can see what is happening during this process and enter 'Setup'. Most pc's that don't detect video or detect something wrong with the video circuit (ie:voltage) will not normally continue booting and will halt and throw the audible code out, providing there is an on-board speaker.

This would answer what you posted in this thread about......, even though there was no question.

In General:
If you recently installed a graphics card just before this issue then there could be a compatibility issue or driver issue.
Or, the on-board graphics chip or circuit could have malfunctioned and gone bad which could be fixed by installing a graphics card. But this is just generally speaking and your system not booting because of the graphics issue would be a different question based on more specifics about your system hardware, circumstances surrounding the the time period prior to the problem, ect.